# Как создать событие для динамически созданных ячеек таблицы?

Tags: javascript, html

Как в JavaScript реализовать такое:

начало цикла

создаю ячейку `var td1 = document.createElement('td');`

её клик `td1.onclick = myFunc(td1);`

конец цикла

сама функция `function myFunc(elem){consol.log(elem.value)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ошибка в строке:

```
td1.onclick = myFunc(td1);
```

Функция в данном случае должна **возвращать функцию**, которая и будет обработчиком.

```
function myFunc(elem){
    return function(){
        consol.log(elem.value);
    }
}
```

Либо нужно присваивать непосредственно функцию

```
td1.onclick = myFunc;
```

тогда `this` внутри `myFunc` будет указывать на нужную ячейку таблицы

```
function myFunc(){consol.log(this.value)}
```

---

Следующая ошибка: у ячеек таблицы нет свойства `value`. Поэтому во всех приведенных выше случаях будет выведено *undefined*.

Вместо этого можно выводить `innerHTML`, либо `textContent`